# How do we know $\mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is an embedding and $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ a projection for $n > k$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions

These were just off hand comments our professor made in class today at the end of the lecture. How do I prove these? He also said something about the space of matrices $M_{n \times k}$ and $M_{n-k \times n}$ related to the above problem that I missed.

I'm sorry if this is a strange question to ask here, but any help, comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the definitions of embedding and projection?

If $n>k$, there is an obvious embedding $\mathbb{R}^k\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ given by

$$(x_1,\ldots, x_k)\mapsto (x_1,\ldots, x_k, 0,\ldots, 0)$$

and an obvious projection $\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ is given by

$$(x_1,\ldots, x_n)\mapsto (x_1, \ldots, x_{n-k})$$